# Changing parent Div background color on active tab

Tags: jquery, css, class, click

I am trying to figure out how to change the parent div container background color when clicking a tab. I want to have it so that when a tab is active it adds a class to the parent div. Each active tab would add different bg color to the parent.

[Link to the example](https://sgp8.siteground.asia/~uniqtone/hccr/tab-example/)

This is what I would like to do.

[image]

Comment: Please, create a fiddle of the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it in your console, check this

```
var colors = ["red", "black", "yellow"];
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".vc_tta-tabs-list > li").on("click", function() { 
    jQuery(".grve-section").css("background", colors[jQuery(this).index()])
  })
})
```

`$` is not assigned in your code, that's why I changed to `jQuery` here

Comment: Thanks. how'bout if I want to add a background images instead of colours?

Comment: you can use `.css('background-image', 'url(' + colors[jQuery(this).index()] + ')');`

Comment: Thanks! it works but I would like to add different background image for each tab, so there would be total 4 background images.

Actually, if possible, adding a class to '.grve-section' container would solve that problem? I could then add the bg color and image via css.
So clicking tab 1 adds class "tab1" to the .grve-section. clicking tab 2 adds class "tab2" to the .grve-section.
Is that possible?

Comment: yes it is, but will the tricky, bcoz every time you need to clear the last added class, while clicking on the new tab. Like you clicked on tab 2 and you added tab2 class, if you then click tab3 you need to remove the tab2 class and then add tab3

Comment: ah okay. I wonder if something like this could work: 
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/p6p1ezL7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a attribute `data-color` to each tab and then on click you can switch them

```js
$(document).on('click', 'ul>li', function() {
  $(".main").css("background", $(this).data("color"));
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.main {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li data-color="red">red</li>
    <li data-color="blue">blue</li>
    <li data-color="cyan">cyan</li>
    <li data-color="yellow">yellow</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add on-click event to every tab.

```
$(selector).click(function(){
 $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```