# Changing background image of parent div on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I originally posted a question on [how to change a background color on tab click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48315026/changing-parent-div-background-color-on-active-tab/48315358) and I got a good answer.

However, what I would like to do is change parent container background image for each active tab click and that seems to require different code.
Example below of what I would like to achieve:
[Link to the example page](https://sgp8.siteground.asia/~uniqtone/hccr/tab-example)
[image: tab changing background image]

Comment: If you "got a good answer" to your previous question, maybe consider marking it as correct? Also, in order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, rather than simply linking to your website (which could be blocked by filters or antiviral programs).

Comment: thanks for correcting, I just did that.

Comment: The code you've linked to in your prior question could be updated to handle this same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to achieve it, you can find different and better of course

```
$('ul>li:nth-child(1)').on('click', function() {
  $(".main").css('background-image', 'url(image-example1.png)');
})
$('ul>li:nth-child(2)').on('click', function() {
  $(".main").css('background-image', 'url(image-example2.png)');
})
$('ul>li:nth-child(3)').on('click', function() {
  $(".main").css('background-image', 'url(image-example3.png)');
})
$('ul>li:nth-child(4)').on('click', function() {
  $(".main").css('background-image', 'url(image-example4.png)');
})
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.main {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li>red</li>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>cyan</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
  </ul>
</div>


</body>
```